# Ng-Click not firing Button is Clicked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

So have a modal with a two buttons on it. One to close the modal, and one that should fire a function when clicked. I've attached a controller to the modal, and the controller itself works, as it does a successful `console.log()`. The `ng-click` doesn't seem to fire the function though. I think I just need another set of eyes on this, and it is greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div id="forwardCall" class="modal fade" ng-controller="CallCtrl as call">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4>Transfer Call</h4>
          </div>
          <!-- dialog body -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Select Person below</p>
            <div id="transferSelection">
                <?php echo $transferCallSelect; ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- dialog buttons -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="call.hideControls()">Transfer Call</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('CallCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

    console.log("Call Controller");

    function hideControls(){

        console.log("Controls Hidden");
        var well = document.getElementById('callControls');
        well.style.display = 'none';
    }
}]);
```

Comment: `hideControls` isn't available on the `$scope` - try defining as `this.hideControls = function() { ` - also - don't hide any elements explicitly with style - use `ngShow` and `ngHide`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am currently upgrading my code to use AngularJS, so that's why I still have it like this. I'll slowly be switching it over to `ng-show` and `ng-hide`. Thank you for the suggestion though, I more than likely would have overlooked it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `controller as` syntax, you are binding to `this` variable instead of `$scope`. Here is a good post talked about [Controller As Syntax](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax).

[tymejv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1686485/tymejv) gave you a good suggestion. You have to binding the function to `this` when you are using `controller as` syntax. So that you can access the function or variable for this particular controller.

```
this.hideControls = function() { ... };
```

You can binding to function to the `$scope` as well:

```
$scope.hideControls = function() { ... };
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I shall remember this. I'm currently "updating" my code to allow for angular, which is why I have some things like `display = 'none'`

Answer (score 0):

**controller.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('CallCtrl', CallCtrl);

    CallCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

    function CallCtrl($scope, $http) {

        var vm = this;

        console.log("Call Controller");

        vm.well = true;
        vm.hideControls = function () {

            console.log("Controls Hidden");

            //Do not to this! This is not jQuery
            //var well = document.getElementById('callControls');
            //well.style.display = 'none';

            vm.well = false;
        };

    }
}());
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="forwardCall" class="modal fade" ng-controller="CallCtrl as call">
    <div ng-show={{ call.well }}>Some content</div>
</div>
```